# How to use combineLatest and takeUntil rxjs operators in Angular 5

Tags: angular5, rxjs5

I see that in Angular 5 one should be using rxjs operators differently and importing from `'rxjs/operators'` but I'm a little unclear on how it is supposed to work. I have something like:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { combineLatest, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ ... })
export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}


  ngOnInit() {

    this.route_data = Observable.combineLatest(this.route.params, this.route.data,
                             (params, data) => ({params,data}));

    this.route_data_sub = this.route_data.takeUntil(this.destroyed$).subscribe(
      (params_and_data) => {
                            ...
                           }
   }
 ...
}
```

but I'm getting `Observable.combineLatest is not a function` errors. If I add the combineLatest operator the old way it works for combineLatest, but then `takeUntil` is now not found. How is this supposed to be done with Angular 5?

I have quite a bit of rxjs code all over the app and don't know how it is supposed to be rewritten or how to change the imports. Does everything have to be rewritten with .pipe() now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import `combileLatest` use

`import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';`

For `takeUntil`

`import { takeUntil } 'rxjs/operators';`

I found that information:

[combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) 
[takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html)

Answer (score 2):

@Mad Dandelion has the right answer but I figured it's worth showing what it looks like putting it together for anyone running across the same thing. You do have to pipe things like takeUntil. It's a bit of a pain to go through a large app and find all these spots but doesn't take that long. Doesn't look that bad either and has all the benefits in https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md under "why".

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({ ... })
export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}


  ngOnInit() {

    this.route_data = combineLatest(this.route.params,
                                    this.route.data,
                                    (params, data) => ({params,data})
                                   );

    this.route_data_sub = this.route_data
                           .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)) //<-- pipe()
                           .subscribe((params_and_data) => {
                            ...
                           })
   }
 ...
}
```

Also in my case I had some stale dlls serving the older rxjs (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/) so if you run into something that looks like your Observables don't have the pipe property, you might want to make sure the dlls are building properly if you use that.